# How to manually backup synology system files?

Tags: backup, filesystems, restore, synology

I built a synology with 6 HDD drives. The files are only synchronized with Google Cloud. (Basic EXT4) I am afraid that HDD will crash down and I'd need to rebuild the system files, as the hyper backup may won't backup the system files. I looked up the synology file through SCP protocol with Winscp and the files are listed as following:

```
/root ls

@synocalendar
@tmp
bin
config
dev
etc
etc.defaults
initrd
lib
lib32
lib64
lost+found
mnt
proc
root
run
sbin
sys
tmp
usr
var
var.defaults
volume1
volume2
volume3
volume4
volume5
volume6
volumeUSB1
```

I created each volume for each disk. HDD system files are possibly stored in each volume. For example, Volume 4 is listed as following:

```
/volume4$ ls

@GuestImage
@appstore
@database
@eaDir
@iSCSI
@quarantine
@sharesnap
@tmp
F --> personal folder and sync with Cloud
G --> personal folder and sync with Cloud
photo --> personal folder and sync with Cloud`
```

Backup @XXXXX folders, and next time, I'll replace a crashed HDD with a new HDD and, and will restore @XXXXX on the volume. will that work?

Answer (score 0):

No, on those NAS operating system is stored on internal memory. Also the configuration about volumes, shares, services, etc is stored in internal flash memory. Probably this NAS have a function to export config. Do it and keep file outside NAS.

Backup the content of NAS volumes is another story. This sync service you talk about sync only content of volumes as it not need to backup system files.